# can not find cas.log for apereo/cas 4

Tags: cas

I need to configire an apereo/cas in a few of days.

First I build the cas.war 4.2.2 according to https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template. And then I deployed it in tomcat 8.0.36. After I start up the tomcat, I can login by the sample user(casuser: Mellon), but I can't find the cas.log file in tomcat/logs folder and other place by `find / -name cas.log`.

I have copied the log4j2.xml to /etc/cas/ as per the reference. Besides, I can't  any error in tomcat/logs.

Did some one solve this problem or have a clue?

By the way, the log4j2 xml is available at https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template/blob/master/etc/log4j2.xml.

Comment: Please share your log4j2 configuration.

Comment: the log4j2 xml is available at https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template/blob/master/etc/log4j2.xml

Answer (score 1):

Your log4j file describes where the log should be found. You'll file the location inside a file appender.

Answer (score 1):

Your logging configuration doesn't specify a path so the files are going to end up in whatever the current directory is when you start tomcat or whatever tomcat sets the working directory to. That probably isn't what you want.